# how to update Rails.cache TTL on read/fetch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I would like to keep my objects in the Rails cache so long as there is a read within some interval (say 10 minutes). I can successfully set a TTL on cache object creation with:

```
Rails.cache.fetch('key', expires_in: 10.minutes) do
  some_expensive_operation
end
```

But I notice that subsequent cache reads for 'key' do not up the TTL (at least not in my setup, which is Rails 3.2 + Redis).

Is there a way to have `Rails.cache.{fetch,read}` re-up the TTL for cache hits?

My alternative is to do the following, which seems potentially wasteful:

```
result = Rails.cache.read('key') || some_expensive_operation
Rails.cache.write('key', result, expires_in: 10.minutes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a redis-specific solution I came up with:

```
def fetch(key, ttl_seconds)
  cached_value = $redis.get(key)

  if cached_value
    # re-up the TTL
    $redis.expire(key, ttl_seconds)

    result = Marshal.load(cached_value)
  else
    result = yield
    $redis.setex(key, ttl_seconds, Marshal.dump(result))
  end

  result
end

fetch('key', 10.minutes) do
  some_expensive_operation
end
```

I'd prefer something that's cache-provider neutral, but that just doesn't seem to be part of the Rails caching API, unless I've missed something.

Comment: To mimic Memcache TTL I think you need to remove the re-up line. In Memcache the cache will expire after ttl_seconds no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want update TTL on fetch just to make cache store only frequently used records. I guess the reason is cache size.

Just don't do that! Let cache engine to decide what records to keep. If you're using **Memcached** it does this job out of box, you can never bother deleting old records. If you're using **Redis** you need to [configure it as an LRU cache](http://redis.io/topics/lru-cache).